# Does System.Web.Caching utilize an LRU algorithm?

Tags: asp.net, .net, caching, lru

I was just working on the documentation for an open source project I created awhile back called [WebCacheHelper](http://webcachehelper.codeplex.com/). It's an abstraction on top of the existing Cache functionality in System.Web.Caching.

I'm having trouble finding the details of the algorithm used to purge the cache when the server runs low on memory.

I found this text on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cacheitempriority%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> When the Web server hosting an ASP.NET application runs low on memory,
>   the Cache object **selectively purges items to free system memory**. When
>   an item is added to the cache, you can assign it a relative priority
>   compared to the other items stored in the cache. Items to which you
>   assign higher priority values are less likely to be deleted from the
>   cache when the server is processing a large number of requests,
>   whereas items to which you assign lower priority values are more
>   likely to be deleted.

This is still a little vague for my taste. I want to know what other factors are used to determine when to purge a cached object. Is it a combination of the last accessed time and the priority?

Comment: You mean among the items with the same priority?

Comment: @Magnus - Yes. I just updated the question. I'm trying to figure out what the other factors are besides priority.

Comment: Difficult to answer as the algorithm is a bit more complicated than a simple list. You should consult .NET Reference source to find exactly what you want. I think a good starting point of what you're after is this method: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/xsp/system/Web/Cache/cache.cs#6e9f645b254cd93d

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's take a look at the source code. Purging starts from `TrimIfNecessary()` method in `CacheSingle` class. Firstly it tries to remove all expired items in `FlushExpiredItems()` method of `CacheExpires` class. If that's not enough it starts iterating through "buckets" in `CacheUsage.FlushUnderUsedItems()`. Cache usage data/statistics divided into "buckets" according to `CacheItemPriority` and their statistics/LRU treated separately in each bucket. There're two iteration through buckets. The first iteration removes only newly added items (during last 10 seconds). The second one removes other items. It starts removing items from `CacheItemPriority.Low` bucket and its LRU items. It stops when removed enough otherwise continues to next LRU items and higher priority buckets. It doesn't touch `CacheItemPriority.NotRemovable` items as it doesn't add them into usage buckets.